# Is there any api to treat activity stack as queue in android?

Tags: android-activity, queue

usually in android when a new activity or pop up starts the current activity or pop up will be pushed into the stack and will go to background. Is it possible to retain the current activity or pop up and queue the newly started activity or pop up